# php page completely loaded from cache (appcache)

Tags: php, html, caching

I'm still working on a new webpage and I use Wamp on Windows 7.
Yesterday I've created a test.appcache file for my webpage (index.php)

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2014-08-22 

CACHE:
img/footer2.png
css/general.css

#indicate that all other resources/files require an internet connection:
NETWORK:
*
```

Now the problem is that not only the .png and .css is loaded from cache, as I would expect, but the complete webpage is cached and loaded!
(In the php file I'm showing database information, but after changing records, I can't see the changes in the webpage. When I remove the appcache file it does show the correct database information.)

I tried removing the  from the code, but this didn't solve the problem.

Attention: I'm still working on my local machine (localhost)...

Can anyone help me?